# jQuery UI datepicker to epoch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

What is the best way to get a datepicker date in the following format yyyy-dd-mm (yy-dd-mm in datepicker settings) and convert it into epoch time with Javascript?

I was trying to do it like this:

```
var aDate = $("#date").val().split('-');
var epoch = new Date(aDate[0] + "," + aDate[1] + "," + aDate[2]).getTime() / 1000;
```

And a `console.log(epoch)` comes back as `NaN`.

But if I declare epoch as `new Date(2011,10,30).getTime() / 1000;` then there is no problems.
I am guessing the problem is that I am passing in a string, but I have no clue how to solve it as I am new to Javascript.

Edit: I know about the `altDate` and `altFormat` settings in datepicker. But I want to know how to do it without using those setting. Because I will have to do what I am describing above for date + time later.

Comment: what are the values of aDate[0], aDate[1] and aDate[2]?

Comment: you can convert them to integer with parseInt(aDate[0]) etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your date constructor to this:

```
var epoch = new Date(aDate[0], aDate[1] - 1, aDate[2]).getTime() / 1000;
```

We've removed the string concatenation, so it should read the date correctly. Month is represented as `aDate[1] - 1` because month numbers in JavaScript are zero based (January = 0, December = 11), so 1 needs to be subtracted from the month number.

You can find a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qpg24/67/

Comment: This is NOT fully correct - months in the date constructor are 0 based. This means you'll get an epoch that is 1 month too high. The correct constructor is `new Date(aDate[0], aDate[1]-1, aDate[2])`

Comment: @ErwinWessels - You're absolutely correct! I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery UI datepicker's `altDate` and `altFormat` parameters will do this for you automatically.

Check out the "Populate alternate field" example in the [examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field).

Comment: Sure enough, epoch seconds is a valid format. Didn't know it was that specialized. Docs on the format params: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI datepicker has a 'getDate' method that returns the date as a string:

```
Sun Apr 28 2013 13:30:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
```

You can use the 'getTime' method of a Date object to convert this string into milliseconds since the epoch. Using your example code, this would look like:

```
var epoch = new Date( $("#date").datepicker( "getDate" ) ).getTime();
```

This works for jQuery datetimepicker as well (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

> dateFormat: '@',

```
$("#input").datepicker({
    dateFormat: '@',
    maxDate : 0,
    onSelect: function() {
        var input = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        console.log('%c input = ' + input, "color: green;");
    }
});
```